# Why is $\emptyset$ a subset of every set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Please read the details of this question before answering.

I am reading a book in which they say $\emptyset \subseteq S$ for any set $S$.  One justification they give for this is that if $\emptyset \not \subseteq S$, then there must be some element in $\emptyset$ that is not in $S$.  And we conclude that this cannot happen since $\emptyset$ has no elements.

.....But to prove $\emptyset \subseteq S$, we need to show every element of $\emptyset$ is in $S$.  But this is impossible too, since $\emptyset$ has no elements.

I don't get it.  By the way, I am familiar with vacuous truth (i.e., that $\mathrm{false} \implies \mathrm{true}$ is a true statement).  But if we reason the above statements in the way I did, then something isn't right.  The question is, what isn't right?

Comment: Every element of the empty set IS in any set

Comment: @Joao Why can't I say the following: We know $\emptyset \not \subseteq S$ because since $\emptyset$ has no elements, surely one of them is not in $S$.  This seems like the *same* statement as saying "empty set has no elements, so every element is in $S$".

Comment: Saying "every element of the empty set IS in any set" is vacuously true. It would be more precise to say that since $\emptyset$ has no elements it is vacuously true that $a \in \emptyset \implies a \in S$. Similarly, it is also vacuously true that $a \in \emptyset \implies a \notin S$.

Comment: $\emptyset$ has no elements, surely one of them is not in $S$. But it has no elements! All of its elements are in $S$.

Comment: @Joao I have no idea what you just said.

Comment: Yeah I don't really know what I'm saying either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference between $\emptyset \subseteq S$ and $\emptyset \nsubseteq S$ is that the former states that "every element in $\emptyset$ is also an element in $S$" while the latter states that "some element $\emptyset$ is not in $S$".

The second statement is clearly false, since if it were true then you should be able to exhibit some element from the empty set which is not in $S$. Of course, you can't do that since there are no elements in the empty set.

The first statement is true, since it were false, then you should be able to exhibit some element from the empty set which is not in $S$. Of course, you can't do that since there are no elements in the empty set.

So, I guess your confusion stems from wrongly appealing to 'vacuously true' without paying enough attention to the details. A correct application of vacuous implication would be to conclude that by the same argument it holds that $\emptyset \subseteq S^c$, where $S^c$ is the complement of $S$ relative to some universe. This is of course correct, and essentially the same argument.

I hope this helps.

Comment: It definitely does.  And it also goes along with what @Hurkyl was saying in the comments of his/her post.  Thanks to both of you paying attention to the details of my post, now I know that *I* wasn't paying enough attention to details in the first place. Thanks!

Comment: I just want to add the following remark to this answer: For $\emptyset \subseteq S$, we need the following statement to be true: $\forall x(x \in \emptyset \implies x \in S)$.  But, for any $\, x$, the implication is *always* vacuously true because $x \not \in \emptyset$ to begin with.  Thus, the statement is true for all $x$, and so $\emptyset \subseteq S$.  On the other hand, in order for $\, \emptyset \not \subseteq S$, we need the following statement to be true: $\exists x(x \in \emptyset \implies x \not \in S)$.  ...Why is this statement false?  Because its negation...

Comment: Well its negation is $\forall x(x \in \emptyset \land x \in S)$.  But is this statement equivalent to $\forall x(x \in \emptyset \implies x \in S)$?  If so, then the argument is done.  But I'm not sure.

Comment: Here is the correct explanation of my remark after I've done some thinking about it.  As I said above, $\, \emptyset \subseteq S$ is always true because the statement $\forall x(x \in \emptyset \implies x \in S)$ is true (vacuously).  But the statement $\, \emptyset \not \subseteq S$ is true precisely when $\exists x(x \in \emptyset \land x \not \in S)$ is true.  But this statement is $\,$*never*$\,$ true because for an "and" statement to be true, both pieces have to be true, and $x \in \emptyset$ is **always** false.  Thus, $\, \emptyset \not \subseteq S$ is always false.

Answer (score 7):

If $\varnothing$ has no elements, then we don't have to do any work to show that all of them are elements of $S$!

Anyways, you say that we need to show

$$ \forall x: x \in \varnothing \implies x \in E$$

but you say you can't do this, because $x \in \varnothing$ is identically false. Can you articulate why you think that's a valid argument?

Comment: Why can't I say the following: We know $\emptyset \not \subseteq S$ because since $\emptyset$ has no elements, surely one of them is not in $S$.  This seems like the *same* statement as saying "empty set has no elements, so every element is in $S$".

Comment: Every element of $\varnothing$ is indeed not an element of $S$. But that's not what $\varnothing \not\subseteq S$ means: $\varnothing \not\subseteq S$ means that there is an element of $\varnothing$ that is not in $S$. If $\varnothing$ had an element, we could conclude the latter from the former, but it doesn't, so we can't! We could conclude, however, that $\varnothing \subseteq \bar{S}$, where I've used $\bar{S}$ to mean the complement of $S$ (which is a proper class, not a set). In fact, $\varnothing = S \cap \bar{S}$, so it is the largest set that is a subclass of both!

Comment: If every element in $\emptyset$ is not in $S$, then there is some element in $\emptyset$ that is not in $S$ since every element of $\emptyset$ is not in $S$.  See what I did there?

Comment: The proof that  $U \subseteq E$ becomes easier if we make $U$ smaller: we have less work to do.  In the extreme situation when we make $U$ as small as possible (empty), we have no work at all to do in our proof.

Comment: @Math: Yes: you used the hypothesis "there is some element in $\varnothing$" to derive a contradiction. That should not be surprising, because you started with a false hypothesis. The implication $\forall x \in S: P(S) \implies \exists x\in S: P(S)$ is only valid when $S \neq \varnothing$.

Comment: Note that one popular variation of first-order logic does include $\forall x: P \implies \exists x: P$ as one of the rules of inference: this variation is *incapable* of reasoning correctly with an empty domain. Maybe this is the source of your confusion?

Comment: errata: two comments up should have $P(x)$, not $P(S)$

Comment: I think that is exactly what I was asserting was true.  But it was because I was being naive, rather than because I have seen that before.

Answer (score 2):

The rules of logic say a false statement implies anything. Hence $x\in \emptyset\implies x\in E$ for any set $E$.

Comment: Did you even read my question?

Comment: I did. Still, $P\implies Q \iff \sim P\vee Q$.

Comment: I'm not happy with your answer.  It doesn't answer my question.  Sorry.

Comment: It answers. The fact is: you are in fact not familiar with what you said you were.

Comment: @AloizioMacedo So the solution is to just restate what I am not familiar with? Rather than delve into what I don't understand?

Comment: @MathIsHardNoItsNot You said you are familiar with vacuous truth. That's all that's at play here.

Comment: OP was asking what is wrong with his argument for what seems to use the same logic rule, but yields something incorrect. OP said to be aware of vacuous proofs, and not to have any issues with that. The current answer simply restates the logical rule of vacuous implication. It does not address the question OP posed.

Comment: That's a complete different question. Your question is: "Why is ∅ a subset of every set?" and "But if we reason the above statements in the way I did, then something isn't right. The question is, what isn't right?". He answered both of them. The question you are posing here is a complete different one: "Can you help me understand why (false implies true) is true?"

Comment: @IttayWeiss Thank you for not making me feel crazy.