# What is the meaning and difference of { } and ( )

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I know that $(1,2,3) \ne (3,2,1)$ but {1,2,3} = {3,2,1}. But what does it mean actually?

And maybe some explanation on why
1. Ø subset of {0} is true?
2. {x} element of {x} is false?

Comment: $\{\}$ is often used to denote sets: those are unordered and elements there are unique. $()$ denotes the sequence: there you can have repeated elements, and their order does matter

Comment: @Ilya your comment should be posted as an answer, I think.

Comment: @TZakrevskiy: I do not have formal background in set theory, so maybe my intuition would not be formal, so I prefer to leave comments in such cases.

Comment: @Ilya I doubt it has anything to do with set theory, it is merely a question of notation conventions.

Comment: @TZakrevskiy having doubts is exactly what I meant

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/999199/why-is-emptyset-a-subset-of-every-set

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/253818/example-of-set-which-contains-itself

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The round brackets and curly brackets (parentheses and braces) are used in many ways and in many contexts.

But in your case, the round brackets mean the contents are an *ordered n-tuple*, meaning the order of the contents matters. The curly brackets are an *unordered n-tuple*, more commonly called a *set*, where the order of the contents does not matter. There are ways in formal set theory to make the difference more clear, but at this level the description I gave is sufficient. As @quid pointed out, in a set you also do not repeat any of the elements in the list: if you do, the extras are ignored. So, the set $\{1,2,2\}$ is the same as the set $\{1,2\}$, which is of course the same as the set $\{2,1\}$. If I had written round brackets in those lists, they would all have been different from each other.

1) Set $A$ is a subset of set $B$ if every element of $A$ is also in $B$. $Ø$ is the empty set, which has no members. Therefore there is no way you can find a member of $Ø$ that is not a member of $\{0\}$. So, $Ø$ truly is a subset of $\{0\}$. Actually, $Ø$ is a subset of *every* set. There is no way to disprove it!

2) $x$ is an element of $\{x\}$ but $\{x\}$ is not an element of $\{x\}$. Think of it this way. If you put $x$ in a box, you get a box with $x$ in it. $x$ is in the box, but the box is not in itself. In modern set theory (ZF or NBG), the Axiom of Restriction implies that no set is a member of itself. The famous Russell's paradox is based on the possibility of a set being a member of itself. One way to remove the paradox is to state that no set is a member of itself. This cannot be proved from the other axioms, but it makes sense intuitively.

Comment: Did you mean "set $A$ is a **subset** of $B$ if every element of $A$ is also in $B$"?

Comment: @dtldarek: Yes, I did. Thanks for the correction! I have edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thiss is a nice answer. Two points, one technical, one mathematical. 1. To find out who edited something you can click the link in the middle to get the full revision history. 2. IMO there is a slight risk of confusion in saying that the curly brackets are an unordered n-tuple;  usually one considers the set {1,2,2} to be equal to {1,2} and this might also come up at that level. There is also a notion of multi-set (also known by other names) where multiplicity of elements is taken into account while order is disregarded.Unorder n-tuple would capture multi-sets well.

Comment: @quid: Thanks very much for the two points. I did not know about 1, and I did not think about 2 (but I should have). I'll add a comment and edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: @TZakrevskiy: Thanks for attempting to edit and improve my answer, even though I ended up spoiling your edit. At least you pointed out where I needed to finish the job!

Comment: Actually, some set theories allow Quine atoms, i.e. sets that are elements of themselves. The Russel paradox however has no problems with sets containing themselves; instead it constructs (by deliberate use of naive methods to build sets) a set that is element and not element of itself at the same time and *that* is contradictory (and shows that we should be careful what constructions we allow eith sets).

Answer (score 5):

To add to Rory's excellent answer, I want to discuss another point.

It's reasonable to ask "if the only elementary notions are "set" and "element," and sets don't have order, how do you get *ordered* pairs?"

The first part of the answer is to decide what the ordered pair $(a, b)$ should *mean*, and a rather nice answer is that *however* you define it in terms of sets, it should have the property that $(a, b) = (c, d) $ implies that $a = c$ and $b = d$ (even if $a$ and $b$ happen to be equal, in which case all four are equal). Having this property means, for instance, that you won't find that $(3, 2) = (2, 3)$, because that would imply (by the $a = c$ rule) that $3 = 2$.

So here's a definition that has the required property:

We define  $(a, b)$ to be
$$
\{ \{a\}, \{a, b\} \}.
$$

Let's check that this definition really does have the required property. So we'll assume $(a, b) = (c, d)$ and conclude that $a = c$ and $b = d$.

Case 1: $a = b$. Then we have

$$
(a, b) = \{ \{a\}, \{a, b\}\} = \{\{a\}\, \{a\}\} \{\{a\}\}.
$$
So 
$$
\{ \{c\}, \{c, d\} \} = \{\{a\}\}.
$$
When two sets are equal, every element of the first is an element of the second, so 
$$
\{c\} \in \{\{a\}\}
$$
hence 
$$
\{c\}  =\{a\}
$$
hence $c = a$, and we've got half our conclusion. The same argument says that 
$$
\{c,d\} \in \{\{a\}\}
$$
hence 
$$
\{c,d\}  =\{a\}
$$
hence 
$$
d \in \{a\}
$$
hence
$$
d = a.
$$
Since we're in the case $a = b$, we conclude that $d = b$. DONE (with case 1).

In the second case, $a \ne b$. 
We are assuming that $(a, b) = (c, d)$, so 
$$
\{ \{c\}, \{c, d\} \} = \{ \{a\}, \{a, b\} \}.
$$
Hence either case A:
$$
 \{c, d\} =  \{a\}
$$
or case B
$$
 \{c, d\} =   \{a, b\}
$$
must hold. Let's consider case A. Since the two sets are equal, we have
$$
c \in \{a\} \\
d \in \{a\} 
$$
so $c = a$ and $ d = a$, so our original equality becomes
\begin{align}
\{ \{c\}, \{c, d\} \} = \{ \{a\}, \{a, b\} \} \\
\{ \{a\}, \{a, a\} \} = \{ \{a\}, \{a, b\} \}\\
\{ \{a\}, \{a\} \} = \{ \{a\}, \{a, b\} \}\\
\{ \{a\} \} = \{ \{a\}, \{a, b\} \}\\
\end{align}
Hence, since every element of the right-hand set must be an element of the left-hand one, we have
$$
\{a, b\} = \{a\}
$$
and thus $b = a$, which is a contradiction.

That leaves us in case $B$, in which $a \ne b$ and 
$$
\{a, b\}  =  \{c, d\}.
$$

Because $a \ne b$, we have $\{a\} \ne \{a, b\}$ (you should check this, be a proof very like the ones in the steps above!). Thus $\{a\} \ne \{c, d\}$ (because this latter set is equal to $\{a, b\}$). Hence we must have 
$$
\{a\} = \{c\}
$$
so $a = c$. Our hypothesis for this case now becomes $a \ne b$ and 
$$
\{a, b\} = \{a, d\}.
$$
The element $b$ of the left-hand set must be in the right-hand set. The only two choices are $b = a$ and $b = d$ (or both, if by some chance it turns out that $a = d$...but it won't.)

The first case explicitly contradicts the hypothesis for this case, so the second must hold. We have that $b = d$, and we're done.

========================================

That's a lot of formal rigamarole just to prove this little property of ordered pairs. The good news is that you never again have to think about it: you've got a new notation, and a definition for it that gives it the property you care about, and you will never look at the proof again (unless, like me, you teach it someday, or write an answer to SE question!).

Comment: I would add to this that given an ordered pair construction, you can make ordered triples or ordered $n$-tuples by a construction like $(a,b,c,d)=(((a,b),c),d)$ or $(a,b,c,d)=\{(1,a),(2,b),(3,c),(4,d)\}$.

Comment: Good point, Mario. I should have said that.